# The difference between どうやって and どうやったら

Tags: word-choice, words

What is the difference between どうやって and どうやったら?

Answer (score 1):

As in the other answer, it can be the same in some cases. However, they may have the different nuance. My analysis is the following:

If you say どうやって大阪に行けますか？ at the tourist agency. You might be asking what kind of choice I have for going to Osaka? By overnight bus? By train? By ship? It's simply asking about choices.

If you say どうやったら大阪に行けますか? at the tourist agency, It can be semantically the same. You are asking the choices. However this time, you are more of saying you do want to go to Osaka in addition to simply asking choices.

Comment: I also think of the difference in nuance between どうやって and どうやったら as similar to saying "How can/do I ..." and "What should I do to...", respectively. Using the example in the post, どうやって = How can I go to Osaka?, どうやったら = What should I do so I can go to Osaka? I can't explain it very well so I am commenting this as a complement to this answer.

Comment: How about　どのように大阪に行けますか。

Comment: @Artificial Stupidity It can be the same meaning, but sounds like just asking possible route itself, kind of algorithm. You don't have a clear intention to go Osaka comparing to どうやって/どうやったら.